# How to select what properties are going to be updated in the PATCH operation from Spring-data-rest?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-rest, spring-mongodb

Let's say I have the Person class:

```
class Person{ 
  private String id; 
  private String name; 
  private Date creationDate;
}
```

Using spring data rest I can Patch this entity like:

*http://resourcehost/people/personId*

With a json petition body:

```
{
  "name":"Jon Smith",
  "creationDate":"2020-08-01 00:00:00"
}
```

I want my customer to be able to update the name but I don't want the consumer updating the "creationDate" field.

How can I configure whether or not the properties should be updated using the PATCH operation?

I'm using Spring boot statrters version 2.2.2.RELEASE

Comment: If you don't what to update creationDate don't set it on update. I am assuming that class Person is an entity class with getters and setters.

Comment: I'm asking about the consumer. I cannot control what the API consumer will send as petition body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore updates to a specific field of the entity on a `PATCH` request by annotating it with `@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)`, as it has been done in the class below.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class ModelBase implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "creation_time")
    @CreatedDate
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    private LocalDateTime creationTime;

    @Column(name = "modified_time")
    @LastModifiedDate
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    private LocalDateTime modifiedTime;
}
```

Spring Data REST will not throw an exception, it will simply ignore the field. By using [Projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#projections-excerpts) you should be able to ignore this behaviour.